What TLS version is Databricks Runtime Version 7.3 LTS using?
According to docs all current DataBricks instances use TLS 1.2 Data security and encryption - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn
7.3 is end of support form 2022 - what TLS version is 7.3 using?

If that version is out of support since 2022, why do you care?

If you still have access to that version then why not simply test? Chances are very high that it is TLS 1.2 as this was used for a long, long time, although it unfortunately only hit 50% share in 2017. TLS 1.3 has been released quite a while ago and they should be very ashamed not using it yet.

I am using the TLS version 1.3:
import requests
print(requests.get('https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check', verify=True).json()['tls_version'])

Results:
TLS 1.3


The above makes an HTTP GET request to the URL
https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check.
This URL is part of a website that checks the SSL/TLS configuration of your connection.

To get TLS version:
import ssl
tls_version = ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
print("TLS version:", tls_version)

Results:
TLS version: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 


otk can you check if the above solution helped you?
